# DB Link from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, dblink

I am trying to connect Oracle 11G user to SQL server 2012 database. I have created a data source using ODBC system DSN. I have configured oracle heterogeneous service under folder $ORACLE_HOME\hs\admin, but when I try to ping the new listener it throws exceptions. My configurations are as follows:

My initdg4odbc configurations:

```
# This is a sample agent init file that contains the HS parameters that are
# needed for the Database Gateway for ODBC

#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = OTOSS
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF


#
# Environment variables required for the non-Oracle system
#
#set <envvar>=<value>
```

Listener configurations

```
# This is a sample listener.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

OTOSS =
 (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))

SID_LIST_OTOSS=
  (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC=
         (SID_NAME=OTOSS)
         (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
         (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
       )
      )

#CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER = 0
```

tnsnames configurations

```
# This is a sample tnsnames.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

OTOSS =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=OTOSS))
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "it throws exceptions" isn't enough information in order to help, since which exceptions it is throwing is actually important... That said, take a look at my article at dba.stackexchange on HS db links, especially how to debug each step, in order to trace down where the failure is taking place: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111985/step-by-step-establish-a-connection-between-sql-server-2014-and-oracle-12c/134578#134578

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but still, maybe it will help.
Try to change the initdg4odbc.ora name to initOTOSS.ora, make sure that system DSN is named OTOSS and also that the system DSN corresponds the architecture needed (32 or 64 bits). And then, if using Windows system, reboot and it should work.
For more details, please use the configs from this question:
[Connect MS SQL to Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425521/connect-ms-sql-server-database-to-oracle-11g-database)